# Importing Data using MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord to import data from plist. I'm using code less import as explained in this tutorial [Importing Data Made Easy](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/).

I have two entities Manufacturer and Car, they have one to many and one to one relation respectively.

[image: Core Data Model]

Plist structure

[image]

This import work fine

```
NSArray *manufacturers = ...

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        [manufacturers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [Manufacturer MR_importFromObject:obj inContext:localContext];
        }];
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

}];
```

But this is **not getting imported**

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        [Manufacturer MR_importFromArray:manufacturers inContext:localContext];
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

EDIT : Log of manufacturers array

```
[
    {
        "Cars": [
            {
                "CarID": 1,
                "Name": "Civic"
            },
            {
                "CarID": 2,
                "Name": "Jazz"
            },
            {
                "CarID": 3,
                "Name": "City"
            }
        ],
        "ManufacturerID": 1,
        "Name": "Honda"
    }
]
```

Comment: Mh. Do you get any console output? Is the NSError nil? Have you tried to log it? Is manufacturerers maybe nil?

Comment: @Pfitz importFromObject: works fine but importFromArray: is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be like a bug in MagicalRecord, found an [open bug filed](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/pull/447) for this issue.

`MR_importFromArray:` was using `MR_saveWithBlock:` replacing with `saveWithBlockAndWait:` solves the issue. [Bug Fix](https://github.com/badeen/MagicalRecord/commit/67d6d0c5948d4024fa59bbb60ca7be01464be692)