# EXC_BAD_ACCESS for MR_importFromObject with swift

Tags: swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm new in swift, and i'm having a problem when i try to import data with magical record, with objective C it's works like a charme :

```
let importedUser = User.MR_importFromObject(dic) as! User
```

I'm getting a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**, i try to enable zombie objects in vain. apparently it crashes here:

```
 results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

For me the context isn't null.

Comment: Hello does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209985/importing-data-using-magicalrecord

Comment: Usually when you get this error, it means that you're missing something that's necessary to run that exact line of code or other lines.

Comment: More code please. Such as the execute FetchRequestFunction.

Comment: your request could still be nil for example where executeFetchRequest doesn't have optional params. We need more code to help.

Comment: Are you sure the dictionary you are importing from actually has valid data in it? If 'dic' is null or has data that MR can't parse it could cause an error like that. I would also reccomend turning on sql logging if you haven't already and make sure that fetch request is actually doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

MagicalRecord has fix some bug, you can update it. [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)